# Create RSS feed from webpage/ Display changes from external webpage

Tags: php, web-applications, rss, screen-scraping

I am Creating a web application that will get homework from schools website. 
I have been creating rss feeds for the website using dapper Creating an rss feed converting that into html and then putting that into an Iframe on my website. 
I think there has to be a better way to do this.
I don't care what language this would be done in but i would prefer to do it client-side with php or javascript.
I'm intermidiete level php and not so good at java script.
If you could provide detailed explanation with some code that would be great.
also I have legal permission from my school which will be the first for this to go live to get the homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are about create an php application to retrieve the rss from external site (which already have a specific url). Well, i think its better to build a public API first at the source app/external site, to get more multimedia support.

But if you're have no problem with parsing an xml format into html directly, then you can use cURL instead iFrame(or if you didnt have cURL installed in your php, you can modify lil bit and use my [Proxy Library](https://github.com/toopay/CI-Proxy-Library),a PHP class  which enables you to make call to internal and external site with general HTTP request by opening a socket connection to the remote host, originally writen as Codeigniter Library.)

That way, it will be easier to presenting a html view/page rather than proccess it via iFrame.

Comment: No, The external Site doesn't Have RSS
using dapper(http://open.dapper.net) I scrape their content(with permission of couirse) turning the page into an RSS feed which I then converteed to HTML and then presented it in an iframe